# parse one field from an JSON array into bash array

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell-script, array, json

I have a JSON output that contains a list of objects stored in a variable. (I may not be phrasing that right)

```
[
  {
    "item1": "value1",
    "item2": "value2",
    "sub items": [
      {
        "subitem": "subvalue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item1": "value1_2",
    "item2": "value2_2",
    "sub items_2": [
      {
        "subitem_2": "subvalue_2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I need all the values for item2 in a array for a bash script to be run on ubuntu 14.04.1.

I have found a bunch of ways to get the entire result into an array but not just the items I need

Answer (score 33, accepted):

##### Using [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```
readarray arr < <(jq '.[].item2' json)
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

If you need a more hardened way:

```
readarray -td '' arr
```

for inputs with newlines or other special characters, avoiding word splitting.

##### Output:

```
value2
value2_2
```

##### Check:

Process Substitution `>(command ...)` or `<(...)` is replaced by a temporary filename. Writing or reading that file causes bytes to get piped to the command inside. Often used in combination with file redirection: `cmd1 2> >(cmd2)`.
See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Is it possible to do this from a variable instead of a file? I try to avoid excess filesystem access if I don't need it. Once I pull this array I am done with the json output.

Comment: I tried replacing json with $JSON but jq is only looking for files. The json output is from a API call gathered with curl. Your answer does work if I store the output in a file. I was just hoping to avoid it.

Comment: I also looked through the jq manual but theres nothing helpful. Could I pipe it through jq?

Comment: I actually saved a step and did this: `curl -k https://localhost/api | jq -r '.[].item2'` I wrapped it in `arr=$(curl -k https://localhost/api | jq -r '.[].item2')`

Comment: Great `jq` command, but please don't parse command output into an array with `arr=( $(...) )` (even though it happens to work with the sample input): it doesn't work as intended with embedded or leading/trailing whitespace and can result in accidental globbing.

Comment: @GillesQuenot, ...would you an accept an edit fixing the shell end of this to either not depend on word-splitting, or explicitly setting IFS and disabling globbing to make that word-splitting reliable?

Comment: if item2 has value with space then this command separate them.

Comment: Worked great ,thanks!

Comment: if item2 has value with space then this command separate them. – alhelal Mar 12 '20 at 9:58
 -- Is there any solution for this ???

Comment: In bash (and Bourne-like shells other than zsh), problems are not limited to whitespace (Tab, Newline, Spc), but to characters of `$IFS` and glob characters as leaving a `$(...)` unquoted in list context like that is the split+glob operator.

Comment: It would be more helpful if the array translation from jq applied to ALL formats of json, like lists. The jq -r '.[]' simple outputs a string with values separated by space and the format given here just takes the first value. Not general or translatable.

Comment: Edited post for a more reliable way. Values like `"foobar*"` or `"foo bar"` are **NOT** expanded by shell or word spliting. `*` alone, is **NOT valid JSON.**

Answer (score 9):

The following is actually buggy:

```
# BAD: Output line of * is replaced with list of local files; can't deal with whitespace
arr=( $( curl -k "$url" | jq -r '.[].item2' ) )
```

---

If you have bash 4.4 or newer, a best-of-all-worlds option is available:

```
# BEST: Supports bash 4.4+, with failure detection and newlines in data
{ readarray -t -d '' arr && wait "$!"; } < <(
  set -o pipefail
  curl --fail -k "$url" | jq -j '.[].item2 | (., "\u0000")'
)
```

...whereas with bash 4.0, you can have terseness at the cost of failure detection and literal newline support:

```
# OK (with bash 4.0), but can't detect failure and doesn't support values with newlines
readarray -t arr < <(curl -k "$url" | jq -r '.[].item2' )
```

...or bash 3.x compatibility and failure detection, but without newline support:

```
# OK: Supports bash 3.x; no support for newlines in values, but can detect failures
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a arr < <(
  set -o pipefail
  curl --fail -k "$url" | jq -r '.[].item2' && printf '\0'
)
```

...or bash 3.x compatibility and newline support, but without failure detection:

```
# OK: Supports bash 3.x and supports newlines in values; does not detect failures
arr=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
  arr+=( "$item" )
done < <(curl --fail -k "$url" | jq -j '.[] | (.item2, "\u0000")')
```

Comment: But does not handle values with a newline in them :-(

Comment: But I want the *values* in my array, not the encoded strings.  See my answer below.

Comment: @jrw32982, gotcha. You've got two choices, then, either using `"\u0000"` (NULs) as separators, or `@sh`.

Comment: @jrw32982, ...edited to show the former, since there are already two answers (one of them yours) with the latter. (Also, I consider using `eval` unnecessarily a nonstarter).

Comment: Note that `bash`'s `readarray` now supports `readarray -td ''` to read NUL-delimited data into an array.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, good point. I don't suppose you'd remember which release that was added in? I'd want to change the "4.x" comment to be more specific if amending to demonstrate it.

Comment: That would be 4.4

Comment: To *detect failure*, you can do `{ readarray -td '' array && wait "$!"; } < <(...)`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `jq` to produce a shell statement that you evaluate:

```bsh
eval "$( jq -r '@sh "arr=( \([.[].item2]) )"' file.json )"
```

Given the JSON document in your question, the call to `jq` will produce the string

```bsh
arr=( 'value2' 'value2_2' )
```

which is then evaluated by your shell.  Evaluating that  string will create the named array `arr` with the two elements `value2` and `value2_2`:

```
$ eval "$( jq -r '@sh "arr=( \([.[].item2]) )"' file.json )"
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${arr[@]}"
"value2"
"value2_2"
```

The `@sh` operator in `jq` takes care to properly quote the data for the shell.

Alternatively, move the `arr=( ... )` part out of the `jq` expression:

```bsh
eval "arr=( $( jq -r '@sh "\([.[].item2])"' file.json ) )"
```

Now, `jq` only generates the quoted list of elements, which is then inserted into `arr=( ... )` and evaluated.

If you need to read data from a `curl` command, use `curl ... | jq -r ...` in place of `jq -r ... file.json` in the commands above.

Comment: Somehow, this question sat here for a couple of years, without an accurate answer.  I just discovered the solution (answered separately here) and now I see you've posted almost the exact same answer only a few minutes before me.  If only you'd posted this before, it would have saved me figuring it out on my own!

Comment: @jrw32982 I don't think I saw this question before, but Charles just edited [their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314379/116858) which bumped the question to the top of the home page, where I spotted it.

Comment: Yes, that's the only approach so far that handles arbitrary values. `jq` even happens to support non-text values in its strings as an extension over standard json. It seems to be using the safest form of quoting (`'...'`). I note that it transforms a NUL byte to `\0` and doesn't quote numbers nor `false`/`true` though that should be fine. As usual, note that it may transform numbers (like change `1e2` to `100` or `infinity` to `1.7976931348623157e+308`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Do you think it's an issue that some values are left unquoted? If so, one could pass the data through `tostring` before letting `@sh` format them.

Comment: I don't expect it would here. There are context where not quoting numbers can be an issue (like in `echo '2'>file` vs `echo 2>file`), but no here I'd say.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas or Kusalananda: I could not find a way to set the positional parameters with `jq` because it separates values with newlines.  So `eval "set -- $( some-jq-expression )"` doesn't work.  Of course one could always set an array and then use the array to set the positional parameters.  Is there another way?

Comment: @jrw32982 You may want to ask a separate question about that. However, I have no issue setting the positional parameters with `eval "set -- $( jq -r '...' )"`. Testing with e.g. `printf '"%s"\n' "$@"`.  I don't really see what the issue is.

Comment: Try it with the example json file in my answer to this question.  Replace the `eval` statement with `eval "set -- $(jq -r ' .[].item2 | @sh ' json)"`.

Comment: @jrw32982 You're getting two separate lines from `jq`. What you want for the `jq` expression is `[.[].item2] | @sh`.  Note the added `[...]`. You want to convert an array, not two individual values.

Comment: Nice.  That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

To handle arbitrary values:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF >json
[
  {
    "item1": "value1",
    "item2": "  val'\"ue2  ",
    "sub items": [
      {
        "subitem": "subvalue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item1": "value1_2",
    "item2": "  value\n2_2  ",
    "sub items_2": [
      {
        "subitem_2": "subvalue_2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
EOF
eval "arr=( $(jq -r ' .[].item2 | @sh ' json) )"
printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Output:

```
<  val'"ue2  >
<  value
2_2  >
```

Putting together some of the other solutions in this question mentioned in comments and answers from @CharlesDuffy, @StéphaneChazelas, @Kusalananda:

```
#!/bin/bash
v1='a\nb  \n'   
v2='c'\''\"d  '   # v2 will contain <c'\"d  >  
printf '$v1=<%s>\n$v2=<%s>\n\n' "$v1" "$v2"

>json printf "%s\n" "[ \"$v1\", \"$v2\" ]" 
printf 'JSON data: '; cat json
printf '\n'

eval "arr=( $( cat json | jq -r '.[] | @sh ' ) )" 
printf '$arr[0]:<%s>\n$arr[1]:<%s>\n\n' "${arr[@]}"

set -- 
eval "set -- $( cat json | jq -r '[.[]] | @sh ' )" 
printf '$1:<%s>\n$2:<%s>\n\n' "$1" "$2"

{ readarray -td '' arr2 && wait "$!"; } < <( 
   cat json | jq -j '.[] | (., "\u0000") '
)
printf 'rc=%s\n$arr[0]:<%s>\n$arr[1]:<%s>\n\n' "$?" "${arr2[@]}"

{ readarray -td '' arr3 && wait "$!"; } < <( 
   { echo x; cat json; } | jq -j '.[] | (., "\u0000") '
)
printf 'rc=%s\n' "$?"
```

Output:

```
$v1=<a\nb  \n>
$v2=<c'\"d  >

JSON data: [ "a\nb  \n", "c'\"d  " ]

$arr[0]:<a
b  
>
$arr[1]:<c'"d  >

$1:<a
b  
>
$2:<c'"d  >

rc=0
$arr[0]:<a
b  
>
$arr[1]:<c'"d  >

parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
rc=4
```

Comment: See also @Kusalananda's answer, posted a few minutes before mine.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `echo x`? Is that to trigger a failure case, and thus test whether `rc` is set correctly?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Correct; to cause a failure in the call to `jq`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to sputnick I got to this:

```
arr=( $(curl -k https://localhost/api | jq -r '.[].item2') )
```

The JSON I have is the output from an API. All I needed to do wans remove the file argument and pipe `|` the output of curl to jq. Works great and saved some steps.

Comment: That code's actually a bit buggy. Look at what happens if you have a result element of `*` -- it'll get replaced with a list of files in your current directory.

Comment: Similarly, an `item2` value with whitespace in it would become more than one array element.

Answer (score 0):

as an easy alternative, look at `jtc` tool (at https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc),
to achieve the same thing (as in jq's example):

```
bash $ arr=( $(jtc -w '<item2>l+0' file.json) )
bash $ printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
"value2"
"value2_2"
bash $
```

explanation on `-w` option: angular brackets `<...>` specify search entire json, suffix `l` instructs to search labels rather than values, `+0` instructs to find all occurrences (rather than just first one).

Comment: Same bug as all the `arr=( $(jq ...) )` answers, insofar as the contents are being string-split and glob-expanded to populate the array -- meaning spaces (not just newlines) create new elements, and elements that look like a glob expression are replaced by files that expression matches.