# looping through JSON array in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, json, jq

Below is the curl command output (file information about branch), need script or command to print file name, filetype and size.

I have tried with `jq` but was able fetch single value ( `jq '.values[].size'`)

```
{
  "path": {
    "components": [],
    "name": "",
    "toString": ""
  },
  "revision": "master",
  "children": {
    "size": 5,
    "limit": 500,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "values": [
      {
        "path": {
          "components": [
            ".gitignore"
          ],
          "parent": "",
          "name": ".gitignore",
          "extension": "gitignore",
          "toString": ".gitignore"
        },
        "contentId": "c9e472ef4e603480cdd85012b01bd5f4eddc86c6",
        "type": "FILE",
        "size": 224
      },
      {
        "path": {
          "components": [
            "Jenkinsfile"
          ],
          "parent": "",
          "name": "Jenkinsfile",
          "toString": "Jenkinsfile"
        },
        "contentId": "e878a88eed6b19b2eb0852c39bfd290151b865a4",
        "type": "FILE",
        "size": 1396
      },
      {
        "path": {
          "components": [
            "README.md"
          ],
          "parent": "",
          "name": "README.md",
          "extension": "md",
          "toString": "README.md"
        },
        "contentId": "05782ad495bfe11e00a77c30ea3ce17c7fa39606",
        "type": "FILE",
        "size": 237
      },
      {
        "path": {
          "components": [
            "pom.xml"
          ],
          "parent": "",
          "name": "pom.xml",
          "extension": "xml",
          "toString": "pom.xml"
        },
        "contentId": "9cd4887f8fc8c2ecc69ca08508b0f5d7b019dafd",
        "type": "FILE",
        "size": 2548
      },
      {
        "path": {
          "components": [
            "src"
          ],
          "parent": "",
          "name": "src",
          "toString": "src"
        },
        "node": "395c71003030308d1e4148b7786e9f331c269bdf",
        "type": "DIRECTORY"
      }
    ],
    "start": 0
  }
}
```

expected output should be something like below

```
.gitignore    FILE     224

Jenkinsfile   FILE     1396
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/630274/42620 for a way to convert a json array to a bash array.  Then use normal shell looping.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the use case provided in the Question, @JigglyNaga's answer is probably better than this, but for some more complicated task, you could also loop through the list items using `keys`:

from `file`:

```
for k in $(jq '.children.values | keys | .[]' file); do
    ...
done
```

or from string:

```
for k in $(jq '.children.values | keys | .[]' <<< "$MYJSONSTRING"); do
    ...
done
```

So e.g. you might use:

```
for k in $(jq '.children.values | keys | .[]' file); do
    value=$(jq -r ".children.values[$k]" file);
    name=$(jq -r '.path.name' <<< "$value");
    type=$(jq -r '.type' <<< "$value");
    size=$(jq -r '.size' <<< "$value");
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$type" "$size";
done | column -t -s$'\t'
```

if you have no newlines for the values, you can make it with a single `jq` call inside the loop which makes it much faster:

```
for k in $(jq '.children.values | keys | .[]' file); do
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' name type size \
        <<< "$(jq -r ".children.values[$k] | .path.name,.type,.size" file)"
    printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$name" "$type" "$size";
done | column -t -s$'\t'
```

Comment: is the file is a keyword ? or the json array should be present in file?

Comment: updated the Answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 22):

## Extracting the members

```
jq -c '.children.values[]|[.path.components[0],.type,.size]'
```

- `.children.values[]` outputs every member of the array `.values`.
- `|` pipes the previous result through the next filter, rather like a shell pipe
- `[`...`,`...`,`...`]` makes all the terms inside appear in a single array
- The `-c` option produces "compact" format ie. one object per line

Result:

```
[".gitignore","FILE",224]
["Jenkinsfile","FILE",1396]
["README.md","FILE",237]
...
```

## Formatting the result

If you want to output a neatly-aligned table, that's a task better handled by other tools, such as [`column`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column) or [`paste`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste).

```
jq -c '.children.values[]|[.path.components[0],.type,.size]' | column -t -s'[],"'
```

- `-t` tells `column` to guess the number of columns based on the input
- `-s...` specifies the delimiter character(s)

Result:

```
.gitignore   FILE       224
Jenkinsfile  FILE       1396
README.md    FILE       237
```

This relies on the characters `[`, `]`, `,` and `"` not appearing in your filenames, which is not a safe assumption.

`paste` can also arrange multiple inputs side-by-side.  For this, we can remove the JSON structures altogether, and output raw lines (hat-tip to @muru):

```
jq -r '.children.values[]|.path.components[0],.type,.size' | paste - - -
```

`paste - - -` means 3 columns, all read from the the same source.  This time, the only assumption is that the filenames don't contain newlines.

Comment: add `"` to `-s` and you have the exact output that OP wants

Comment: Or if entries won't have newlines in them: `jq -r '.children.values[] | .path.components[0],.type,.size' | paste - - -`

Comment: @JigglyNaga thanks for the detailed answer 
but I have one more question assume if I want store size value in variable how would I do that , because I want to convert those size values to MB

Comment: then you can use my answer ;-)

Comment: @RoVo Good point, it's only one more unlikely character.

Comment: @SugaturDeekshithSN `jq` can do division (`.size/1024`, or `.size/(1024*1024)` ...)

Comment: @muru Thanks, "no newlines" is more likely to be safe; although `paste`'s single tab doesn't line up some of the later, longer entries.

Comment: @muru in this case its fine assume I need to do little more complex calculations in that case , I think we should store it in some variable

Comment: @SugaturDeekshithSN Please could you [update the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/477210/edit) to show what you want to see?  The current "expected output" can be achieved with the commands I've written so far.

Answer (score 6):

`jq` can render its output into a variety of formats: see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping

For tab-separated output:

```
$ jq -r '.children.values[] | [.path.name, .type, .size] | @tsv' file.json
.gitignore  FILE    224
Jenkinsfile FILE    1396
README.md   FILE    237
pom.xml FILE    2548
src DIRECTORY
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `ramda-cli`:

```
% curl ... | ramda -o tsv '.children.values' 'map flat' 'map props ["path.name", "type", "size"]'
.gitignore      FILE    224
Jenkinsfile     FILE    1396
README.md       FILE    237
pom.xml FILE    2548
src     DIRECTORY
```

First we traverse into the list of values, then map over the list with `flat` to convert each entry which is a deep object structure into a shallow one, with keys separated by dots.

Then, we can map over the list again, and pick the wanted properties based on their paths, represented with strings.

Finally, `-o tsv` takes care of converting the resulting list of lists into tsv format.

To debug or further understand what is happening, you may check what each argument does by removing them one by one from the end of the command and observing the difference in output at each step. They are simply operations (or functions) applied on the data one at a time from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

one liner solution based on *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)* and xargs:

```
bash $ jtc -x'<values>l[+0]<size>l[-1]' -y'<name>l' -y'<type>l' -y'<size>l' your.json | xargs -n3
.gitignore FILE 224
Jenkinsfile FILE 1396
README.md FILE 237
pom.xml FILE 2548
bash $
```

*Note:* there's json irregularity in your file (size key is not present in every record), to exclude it the first argument `-x` is built that way (process only those records where size is present).