# Bash iterate array, detect if empty

Tags: bash

I'm trying to iterate over a variable that might be either `null` or an array of strings.

`ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=null` or `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=['domain.sh]`

I'm a beginner in bash, I read [bash iterate file list, except when empty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239772/bash-iterate-file-list-except-when-empty) but I couldn't figure it out.

I tried two different approaches.

The values of `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES` actually comes from `jq` library, which reads JSON.

```
ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=$(cat now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json | jq --raw-output '.alias')
```

#### Approach 1

```
  ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=['test.sh']

  # Check if there are no aliases configured
  if [ -z "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES" ]
  then
    ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_COUNT=${#ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES[@]}
    echo "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_COUNT alias(es) found. Aliasing them now..."

    # For each alias configured, then alias it to the deployed domain
    for DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS in "${ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_COUNT[@]}"
    do
      echo "npx now alias "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_URL $DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS
      npx now alias $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_URL $DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS --token $ZEIT_TOKEN || echo "Aliasing failed for '$DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS', but the build will continue regardless."
    done
  else
    # $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES is null, this happens when it was not defined in the now.json file
    echo "There are no more aliases to configure. You can add more aliases from your now.json 'alias' property. See https://vercel.com/docs/configuration?query=alias%20domain#project/alias"
    echo "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES"
  fi
```

But with this, even when `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=['something']` it doesn't go into the `then` clause.

#### Approach 2

```
ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=['test.sh']
echo "Alias(es) for current project:" $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES

for DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS in $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES; do
  [ -z "$DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS" ] || continue
  echo "npx now alias "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_URL $DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS
  npx now alias $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_URL $DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS --token $ZEIT_TOKEN || echo "Aliasing failed for '$DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS', but the build will continue regardless."
done
```

Similarly, it seems like `[ -z "$DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS" ]` always evaluate to `true`.

Here is a playground if you'd like:

1. https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/3bs
2. https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/3bo

Comment: `for DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS in "${ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES[@]}"`

Comment: Thanks (your edit replaced the Attempt 1 though ^-^)

Comment: Actually, `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=$(cat now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json | jq --raw-output '.alias')` is what really happens, and since it returns JSON such as `['test.domain']` I assumed it would be similar in bash. (doesn't seem like)

Comment: As for the `then` clause, it has been removed by @schrodigerscatcuriosity edit, I edited again.

Comment: What is `test.sh`? Are you expecting `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=['test.sh']` to run the script `test.sh` and save the script's output in the variable `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES`?

Comment: Bad example, `test.sh` is meant to be a domain, not an executable, could have named  it  `test.xyz` for all that matters

Comment: @Vadorequest, not to put too fine a point on it, you're confusing the issue by not showing the actual situation. For example, when you say "a variable that might be either null or an array of strings", people are going to assume you mean an actual array variable in the language in question, a Bash array. And in that context, `null` is a bit unclear, even though the POSIX text uses it to mean an empty string.

Comment: @Vadorequest, But, looking at what you wrote in the comments, you have `ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=$(cat now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json | jq --raw-output '.alias')`, which is not an array, but a simple scalar string variable. And actually tells us that by `null`, you meant the actual string `null`. (I'm not sure if `jq` can return an empty string there.) But that also tells us that your original data source is a JSON file, and you can use `jq`...

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion, definitely a beginner in bash here. I wanted to avoid overcomplexify things and focus on what I thought was the issue at hand.

Comment: @Vadorequest, also, I'm not exactly sure where you're getting `['test.sh']` from, since AFAIK single quotes are not a valid way to quote strings in JSON, and `jq` produces strings in double quotes.

Comment: As for `['test.sh']` I thought it was a valid representation, didn't think single/double quotes had different meanings.

Comment: @Vadorequest, single quotes are fine for the shell here, no difference to double quotes. But the point is that you were not showing the actual situation, which makes it harder for people to help you. Now. Getting past that, I'm I right to assume that you have a file that contains something like this: `{"alias": ["foo", "bar"], "whatever": "xyzzy"}`, and you want to process the `foo` and `bar` from list in the `alias` field?

Comment: Exactly. This file has been read by `jq`.

Comment: @Vadorequest, thank you. see answer.

Comment: @Vadorequest `jq` knows about the shell's syntax, look at the "Format strings and escaping" part of its manpage. Assuming that you have a json file of the form `{"x":["a\nb","c d","e\n f"]}`, I think that `eval "set -- $(jq -r '.x//empty|@sh' <file)"` (followed by e.g. `for f; do printf '{%s}' "$f"; done`) should do what you want. (You may also omit the `//empty` part or use the `-e` option).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this file:

```
$ cat test.json
{"alias": ["foo", "bar"], "whatever": "xyzzy"}
```

at least my version of `jq` gives this output for `jq --raw-output '.alias[]' < test.json`

```
$ jq --raw-output '.alias[]' < test.json
foo
bar
```

i.e. the entries are on separate lines, which is important, since we can use that to separate them from each other. For example, by reading them to an array with `readarray`. (`<(...)` is a *process substitution*, it makes the output of the command available like it was a file, so `< <(...)` makes it available in stdin. A bit like a pipe, actually, except that pipes run subshells so the read values would not be available after the pipe.)

```
#!/bin/bash
readarray -t entries < <(jq  '.alias[]' < test.json)
if [ "${#entries[@]}" = 0 ]; then
    echo empty array...
fi

# this will not do anything if the array is empty
for entry in "${entries[@]}"; do
    echo "processing entry $entry..."
done
```

To deal with a possibly missing `alias` field, use `.alias[]?` in `jq` instead. Note however, that will deal a non-array string value (like `{"alias": "foo"}`) as empty, so if that's a possibility, we'd need to do something else.

Also, note that if the entries contain newlines, `--raw-output` will print them as-is, so entries with them will show up split to multiple lines, as if they were multiple distinct entries.

---

Alternatively, without process substitution, so this should work with a standard shell, not only with Bash.

```
#!/bin/sh
jq --raw-output '.alias[]' < json.txt | 
(
any=
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    echo "doing something with '$line'..."
    any=1
done
if [ "$any" != 1 ]; then
    echo "empty input..."
fi
)
```

See [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373) as to why the parenthesis are necessary.

---

Now, as to your code:

```
ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES=['test.sh']
```

This would assign the string `[test.sh]` to the variable. That's not the same as assigning the string `["test.sh"]` like you'd get from `jq`, since here, the shell processes the quotes you gave it. They're not processed similarly from the output of a command substitution. That's also a single scalar variable, not an array.

```
if [ -z "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES" ]
```

This tests if the string is the empty string, which probably isn't what you meant. Anyway, `jq`'s `.alias` could give the *string* `null`, which is not the same as an empty string.

```
${#ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES[@]}
```

This will always be `1`, since it's not an array. And for the same reason, the
`for` loop doesn't do what you wanted.

Note that Bash doesn't process JSON itself, if it gets a string like `["foo", "bar"]` from a command substitution, it's just that, a *string*. You need to split it individual entries yourself...

Comment: Thanks for the patience and explanation, I understand much better now. As for your question regarding raw output: `jq --raw-output '.alias[0]'` will return `test.domain` while `jq '.alias[0]'` would return `"test.domain".`

Comment: @Vadorequest, ah, yes, you're right. With `jq --raw-output '.alias'` it didn't change the output and it seems I didn't test again with `.alias[]`

Comment: It didn't change it because it's an array and not a string, but against a string it'd have worked.

Comment: @Vadorequest, yep.

Comment: I get `/home/runner/work/_temp/4d02416d-053b-48be-be58-a70c328e0519.sh: line 21: tfp-gem-v4-preview.vercel.app: command not found` when running `readarray -t entries < <($(cat now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json | jq --raw-output '.alias[]'))`, it somehow tries to run a command. (where `tfp-gem-v4-preview.vercel.app` is what's inside my `alias` array of 1 element)

Comment: @Vadorequest, take the inner command substitution out, just `< <(cat | jq)`. Now you have `$(cat | jq)`, which expands the output to the command line, then `<( )` tries to run what it sees there... (also, the `cat` is not necessary, you can just redirect the input file to `jq`)

Comment: Still trying but getting nowhere. `readarray -t entries < <(jq '.alias[]' < now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json)` errors with `syntax error near unexpected token '<'`

Comment: I also looked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314379/60329 which is similar to your answer.

Comment: @Vadorequest, copied from that comment exactly, it runs in my system (Bash 4.4). Do check that you're actually running Bash, and not some other shell. `/bin/sh` might be a more limited shell in some systems, e.g. in Debian and Ubuntu. But the error message doesn't match what the Dash shell those two use would give.

Comment: I don't know exactly what I'm running under, this script is executed by GitHub Actions, but I'll take a look.

Comment: It had nothing to do with bash, I had tried another command above that was generating the error and forgot about it.

Comment: @Vadorequest, ah, ok.

Comment: Yeah, dumb mistake. Sorry, I saw you took it into account and added a workaround for that edge case. I hope it'll be useful to someone else ;)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to make it work after all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for Attempt #1

It was tricky because of the `null` value, which is not `empty` unlike I first thought.

And the hardest thing was to convert the `jq` JSON array into a bash array using:

```
readarray -t ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES < <(jq --raw-output '.alias[]' < now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json)
```

Big thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615717/60329

```
  ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_JSON=$(cat now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json | jq --raw-output '.alias')
  echo "Custom aliases: " $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_JSON

  # Convert the JSON array into a bash array - See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615717/60329
  readarray -t ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES < <(jq --raw-output '.alias[]' < now.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json)

  # Check if there are no aliases configured (it will return "null" in such case, which is not the same as bash "empty")
  if [ "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES" != null ]
  then
    ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_COUNT=${#ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES[@]}
    echo "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES_COUNT alias(es) found. Aliasing them now..."

    # For each alias configured, then assign it to the deployed domain
    for DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS in "${ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES[@]}"; do
      echo "npx now alias "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_URL $DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS
      npx now alias $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_URL $DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS --token $ZEIT_TOKEN || echo "Aliasing failed for '$DEPLOYMENT_ALIAS', but the build will continue regardless."
    done
  else
    # $ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES is null, this happens when it was not defined in the now.json file
    echo "There are no more aliases to configure. You can add more aliases from your now.json 'alias' property. See https://vercel.com/docs/configuration?query=alias%20domain#project/alias"
    echo "$ZEIT_DEPLOYMENT_ALIASES"
  fi
```

Thank you!

Comment: As I already mentioned in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615697/bash-iterate-array-detect-if-empty/615717#comment1151421_615697), have a look at jq's `//` and `empty` ops and its `@sh` format, instead of trying to do it in the shell. Besides being more complicated, your solution has problems with strings which contain newlines.

Comment: Thanks for pointing those issues out. I'm not likely to change the script because the only expected strings are domain names, and they can't contain weird chars such as newlines. The whole thing is quite complicated/long to test and I'm really not looking forward spending another hour on this. (to be honest)